# How to draw a diagram with the given semantic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, xy-pic

I need to draw a diagram similar to the following:

[image: Diagram]

The task is to draw a diagram with this semantics, not necessarily the same appearance.

Note that in the above diagram `$\sqsupseteq$` denotes a partial order, arrows denote application of a function.

`$\upuparrows$` and `$\downdownarrows$` are certain functions.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel In `xy-pic` I know no way to put `$\sqsupseteq$` inplace of an arrow. `tikz-cd` is for commutative diagrams, my diagram is not exactly a commutative diagram, because of these `$\sqsupseteq$`. I need at least an advise which package to use

Comment: Eh, just because your diagram isn't a commutative diagram doesn't mean you can't use a cd package for it. This seems easily doable. However, it would be helpful if you could provide a MWE or at least packages who contain the math-macros you used in your explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your diagram is not a commutative diagram, the `tikz-cd` package can be used here quite good.

I have added a key `define shortcut` which just passes its two arguments to `\providecommand*` (like `\newcommand*` but doesn’t complain if the macro is already defined). This is used here to create short macro names that will only be valid inside the picture.

The `shift left` and `shift right` key can be used to shift arrows between nodes. It is usually (defaults to `.56ex`) used to shift the arrows by a small amount which is why I changed its default value in your example. The `column sep` is remove so that the `sqsupseteq` isn’t that lonely and the `row sep` gives more space between the two lines.

The `tikz-cd` package (which can also be loaded via `\usetikzlibrary{cd}` also loads the `quotes` package which enables you to use `"<content>"` to easily add nodes along an path. (Load also the `babel` library if you use the `babel` package which defines `"` as an active character.)

If you want to have the correct math spacing around `\sqsupseteq` more fine-tuning is needed.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ID}{ID}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\tikzcdset{define shortcut/.code 2 args=\providecommand*#1{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  shift left/.default=.5cm,
  define shortcut/.list={
    \dda\downdownarrows,
    \uua\upuparrows,
    \Strd{\textsf{Strd}},
    \ua{\uparrow}
  },
  column sep=+0pt,
  row sep=large,
  ]
\dda \ID^{\Strd}_{\uparrow A[n]}
  \dar[shift right, "\uua"]\dar[shift left, <-, "\dda"]
  & \sqsupseteq
    & \ua^{\Strd}\id_{A[n]} = \id^{\Strd}_{\ua A[n]}
      \dar[shift right, "\uua"]\dar[shift left, <-, "\dda"] \\
%
\ID^{\Strd}_{\uparrow A[n]} & \sqsupseteq & \uua\ua^{\Strd}\id_{A[n]} = \uua\id^{\Strd}_{\ua A[n]}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```